# Is Matthew 11:12 stating kingdom of heaven is associated with exciting and meaningful eventfulness?

Tags: greek, john-the-baptist, heaven, kingdom-of-god, kingdom

I suppose the perspective that I am about to expound is already buried deep within one of the answers and/or comments of the following 2 stackoverflow Q & A postings, but I wanted to narrow down and emphasize in this posting in order to see if said perspective is accurate and/or correct:

1. [What is the meaning of "violence" in Matthew 11:12?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8380/what-is-the-meaning-of-violence-in-matthew-1112)
2. [In Matthew 11:12 what does it mean for the kingdom of heaven to "suffer violence"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/14021/in-matthew-1112-what-does-it-mean-for-the-kingdom-of-heaven-to-suffer-violence)

> Matthew 11:11-15  (NASB)
>
> 11 Truly I say to you, among those born of women
> there has not arisen anyone greater than John the Baptist! Yet the one
> who is [m]least in the kingdom of heaven is greater than he. **12 From
> the days of John the Baptist until now the kingdom of heaven
> [n]suffers violence, and violent men [o]take it by force.** 13 For all
> the prophets and the Law prophesied until John. 14 And if you are
> willing to accept it, John himself is Elijah who [p]was to come. 15 He
> who has ears to hear, [q]let him hear.

> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Nestle 1904
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν ἡμερῶν Ἰωάνου τοῦ
> Βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν βιάζεται, καὶ βιασταὶ
> ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Westcott and Hort 1881
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν ἡμερῶν
> Ἰωάνου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν βιάζεται, καὶ
> βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Westcott and Hort / [NA27 and UBS4
> variants]
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν ἡμερῶν Ἰωάνου / Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ
> βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν βιάζεται, καὶ βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: RP Byzantine Majority Text 2005
>
> Ἀπὸ δὲ
> τῶν ἡμερῶν Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν
> βιάζεται, καὶ βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Greek Orthodox Church
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν ἡμερῶν
> Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν βιάζεται, καὶ
> βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Tischendorf 8th Edition
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν
> ἡμερῶν Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν βιάζεται,
> καὶ βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Scrivener's Textus Receptus 1894
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ
> τῶν ἡμερῶν Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν
> βιάζεται, καὶ βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.
>
> ΚΑΤΑ ΜΑΤΘΑΙΟΝ 11:12 Greek NT: Stephanus Textus Receptus 1550
>
> ἀπὸ δὲ
> τῶν ἡμερῶν Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν
> βιάζεται καὶ βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν Matthew 11:12 Greek Study Bible
> (Apostolic / Interlinear) ἀπὸ δὲ τῶν ἡμερῶν Ἰωάννου τοῦ βαπτιστοῦ ἕως
> ἄρτι ἡ βασιλεία τῶν οὐρανῶν βιάζεται καὶ βιασταὶ ἁρπάζουσιν αὐτήν.

Could we say that Matthew 11:12 can be rephrased and/or viewed as

From the days of John the Baptist until now the kingdom of heaven [is teeming with activities/events within said kingdom and around said kingdom, and the various activities/events could be good and/or bad], and [good and/or bad people involved in said activities/events are very passionate about said activities/events]

To elaborate on my perspective, wherever Jesus Christ's kingdom is active, there will always be some kind of activities/events that are bad and/or good where the good activities/events might be for the Kingdom of heaven, and the bad are against the kingdom of heaven.

Let's add some bible scripture to prove the aforementioned perspective:

Example of good activity/event that benefits and expands the kingdom of heaven in bible scripture:

> Matthew 3
>
> .....John the Baptist *[a]came, [b]preaching in the wilderness of Judea, saying, 2 “Repent, for   the kingdom of heaven [c]is at hand.”.......5 Then Jerusalem was going out to him, and all Judea and all the district around the Jordan; 6 and they were being baptized by him in the Jordan River,  as they confessed their sins.

Example of bad activity/event going against the kingdom of heaven in bible scripture:

> Matthew 14
>
> 3 For when Herod had John arrested, he bound him and put
> him in prison because of Herodias, the wife of his brother
> Philip...................“Give me here on a platter the head of John
> the Baptist.” 9 Although he was grieved, the king commanded it to be
> given because of his oaths, and because of [e]his dinner guests. 10 He
> sent and had John beheaded in the prison..............

LOL, I suppose I'm just asking:

Is Matthew 11:12 saying that the kingdom of heaven is surrounded by exciting and meaningful events regardless if they are for or against the kingdom of heaven? (Are there important purposes associated with said events? )

In other words, it's **Not** some silly philosophical thought experiment that raises questions regarding observation and perception like:

If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?

Comment: It means that if one wants to enter the kingdom, one has to struggle (Ephesians 6:11-12).

Comment: It means what Paul means when he says to Timothy : _Fight the good fight of faith, lay hold on eternal life_. [1 Timothy 6:12 KJV].

Answer (score 1):

**Is Matthew 11:12 stating Kingdom of Heaven is associated with exciting and meaningful eventfulness?**

Matthew 11:12 [KJV]

> "And from the days of John the Baptist until now the Kingdom of Heaven suffereth violence, and the violent take it by force."

Meaning : **The Children of Israel have been enslaved / taxed forcibly by nations (Egypt, Babylon, Rome) and have been left in poverty (spiritually by traditional worship of foreign idols & monetarily through taxes/debts).**

**Where is the Kingdom of Heaven?**

> "The Kingdom is inside of you, and it is outside of you. When you become acquainted with yourselves, then you will be recognized. And you will understand that it is you who are children of the living father. But if you do not become acquainted with yourselves, then you are in poverty, and it is you who are the poverty."

[http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/thomas/gospelthomas3.html ]

Meaning : **You are a child & servant of Israel the royal family. If you do not recognize your fellow prince / princess suffering in poverty, then you leave your Father's kingdom in poverty.  Do not steal the wealth of Israel by neglecting the poor, the outcast, or mistreating the weak. Return & Share your Father's Wealth / Torah by becoming acquainted spiritually as brothers & sisters in recognition of your royal family. Acknowledge your family by forgiving their debts, otherwise your Father's family remains in poverty.**